# How do I separate digits in a number and then add them together in Java?

Tags: java

Alright so the code I'm working on is suppose to take an input that is a 4-digit number, take that number apart and add each digit together and print it out.

Example:
2683 would be the input and 19 would be printed out afterwards.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a four-digit number: ");
    int fourDigiter = scan.nextInt();
    
    String number = String.valueOf(fourDigiter);

  }
}
```

This is what I have at the moment.  I already got the input made into a string, now I just need to find a way to separate each individual character in the string.  After that I need to somehow also turn those strings/characters back into integers to add together.

Comment: I think it does, huh I probably should've looked a little longer through questions before posting my own.

Comment: When you use a proper search engine (the one here on Stack Overflow is not good), then use `site:stackoverflow.com java` there and then your additional search terms. This limits the results to ones from stackoverflow.com containing java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a string. You can take the integer mod 10 (`% 10`) to get the last digit, and divide it by 10 to get rid of the last digit:

```java
int sum = 0;
while (fourDigiter > 0) {
    sum += fourDigiter % 10;
    fourDigiter /= 10;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```